# Как получить XMLDocument перед отправкой SOAP сообщения

Tags: c#, xml, soap, wcf

Добрый день.
Столкнулся со следующим вопросом: 
Есть некий Web-service стороннего разработчика. известен его wsdl. в vs2010 генерирую прокси класс на основе этой wsdl. Создаю экземпляр класса, заполняю его поля.

Теперь собственно вопрос: как получить текст SOAP сообщения, не отправляя его?

Возможно вопрос и глупый, но наткнулся на собственную дремучесть и не могу найти ответ

Answer (score 1):

[Как сериализовать объект как поток XML с кодировкой SOAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/d5wt2he6(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Спасибо. не совсем то что имел ввиду но можно и так попробовать.